# Transformation of negative reaction time values?

Tags: p-value, data-transformation

I am looking at the difference in mean reaction time change between 2 populations. Although I subtracted the new reaction time from the original(there was mostly a reduction in reaction time across the population) there are still some negative mean change values.

Shall I proceed in using these negative values in linear regression models and Mann-Whitney U tests or do I need to transform the data?

p.s reaction time is non-normal and usually <0.1s

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing data, but (1) sometimes reaction times are better analysed as speeds, 1 / time, assuming no time is zero! (2) sometimes logarithms work fine, with the same assumption. It's possible either way that differences might be better analysed on a transformed scale rather than on the original scale. Transformations don't affect Mann-Whitney tests (unless trivially if you reverse order).

Comment: Amir ... 1. Why would it matter that a *difference* of two times could be negative?  2. It might make more sense to consider a ratio of times (which is also a ratio of speeds, but the other way up), or possibly their logarithm